# F#: Add and remove event handlers

Tags: silverlight, f#, event-handling

I'm trying to add & remove an event handler from a Silverlight FrameworkElement, but I just can't get the syntax correct.

I want to do something like this:

```
let clickedEventHandler = fun args -> printfn "Click!"
fe.MouseLeftButtonDown.AddHandler( clickedEventHandler)
...
fe.MouseLeftButtonDown.RemoveHandler(clickedEventHandler)
```

What should be the correct way to do this?

Comment: If you're not worried about removing the handler you can use Add. `fe.MouseLeftButtonDown.Add( clickedEventHandler )`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you need to create an instance of delegate:

```
let ch = new MouseButtonEventHandler(fun obj args ->
  printfn "Click!")
```

Then you can use `ch` as an argument to `AddHandler` or `RemoveHanlder`. The reason is, that F# function value isn't actually represented as any delegate type. It has it's own type, which isn't a delegate (see also [another SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111347/what-makes-fsharpfunc-faster-than-func)). You can see the difference if you look at the types in F# interactive (or VS IntelliSense):

```
> (fun (o:obj) (a:MouseButtonEventArgs) -> printfn "Click!") 
val it : obj -> MouseButtonEventArgs -> unit = (...)

> new MouseButtonEventHandler(fun o a -> printfn "Click!") 
val it : MouseButtonEventHandler = (...)
```

What may be confusing is that F# also allows implicit conversion from lambda function value to a compatible delegate type when calling a method, however this works only when you give a lambda function directly as the argument (I think):

```
fe.MouseLeftButtonDown.AddHandler(fun obj args -> 
    printfn "Click!")
```

Another reason why you still need delegates in F# is that delegates have a well-defined comparison semantics (they are compared as any other reference types). For functions, the F# specification doesn't say when they are equal.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it turns out you can do the following:

```
let clickedEventHandler = new MouseButtonEventHandler(fun obj args -> printfn "Click!")
fe.MouseLeftButtonDown.AddHandler( clickedEventHandler)
...
fe.MouseLeftButtonDown.RemoveHandler(clickedEventHandler)
```