# How to return two values from F# to C#

Tags: c#, f#, parameter-passing

I have an F# function returning a string and an array to some C# code. I tried a few ways and did some searching to no avail. How is this done? My F# function (Gen.Best) ends with:

```
(T1 Best).ToString,T2 Best // return a (string) and a (float []) to C#
```

F# shows the return type as (unit -> String) * float []
(T1 Best) is a (float -> float) function.

In my C# code I have:

```
Tuple<string, double[]> Ans = Gen.Best(XData, ResultData);
```

The compiler complains:

> The type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   C:\Users\JDL\Dropbox\Formulas\VS Bogdan\Quirkle\MainForm.cs 139 13  Quirkle

How do I add a reference to the assembly? (I'm new to F#)

and

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit,string>,double[]>' to 'System.Tuple<string,double[]>'
>   C:\Users\JDL\Dropbox\Formulas\VS Bogdan\Quirkle\MainForm.cs 139 46  Quirkle

Comment: What are you returning? Please add the code you're using.

Comment: You can create a class library (.dll) from the F# project, and invoke its methods and access its fields from your C# code.

Comment: You can return tuple. F# tuple compiles to `System.Tuple` in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply compile your F# code as a managed DLL assembly and reference it from your C# code (making your function public, of course), you'll find your function implemented as returning an instance of `System.Tuple<string, float[]>`. This works just fine with C# code.

**EDIT:**

With respect to your edits:

1. Assuming that the missing reference is actually in your C# assembly, then you add a reference to the `FSharp.Core.dll` assembly the same way you'd usually do it. E.g. right-click the "References" item in your C# project, choose "Add Reference...", make sure "Assemblies" is selected, and then find the desired assembly in the list (you can type "FSharp.Core" in the search box to make it easier to find the desired assembly).

Note that in general, you may find it easier and more productive to only expose standard .NET types from your F# assembly. That way, C# code using your F# library doesn't need to reference the .NET F# assemblies, nor do anything special to convert (if needed).

In this case, that would mean using the standard .NET `System.Func<1, TResult>` type instead of the `FSharpFunc<'T, 'U>` type.

See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111347/what-makes-fsharpfunc-faster-than-func#comment39448187_2113832) in a related answer for corroboration of my suggestion. :)

2. The error message regarding the conversion from one tuple type to another relates to your question (in the comment below) about how to convert a function to a string.

Comment: It seems I found most of the answer - (unit -> string) is not the same as a string and that was messing things up. Is there a way to convert a function to a string? For example let adder a b = a + b and then get adder.ToString ?

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's nearly impossible to know how to help you exactly. But re: converting function to a string, please be specific as to what you expect to happen. If your lambda is `a b = a + b`, then what `string` value do you expect to get back? The result of that lambda as applied to two input values? Or a textual representation of the operation itself? The former is not hard at all; the latter could be quite hard, depending on what constraints you're willing/able to put on the problem.

Comment: Thanks - I now have enough on the parameter passing issue so the only remaining issue is converting a function to a string. In my example "let adder a b = a + b" I would like adder.ToString to return "a + b". But if it's not easy to do I have another route I can take.

Comment: @JimLewis: Translating your function to a string that represents the operation of the function itself is a deeply non-trivial problem. You would basically be reimplementing the kind of functionality seen in tools like Reflector or dotPeek: retrieving the `MethodInfo` reference from the function object (either a delegate type or one of F#'s function types), getting the IL from the method in question, and then interpreting that IL to present it in some other form, such as C#, F#, or VB.NET code, or (if you can limit the domain) some mathematically descriptive representation.

Comment: @JimLewis your problem is that you forgot the parentheses in your ToString call.  Specifically, you wrote `(T1 Best).ToString,T2 Best` when you should have written `(T1 Best).ToString(),T2 Best`.  Therefore, the first element of the tuple is not the result of calling ToString(); it is the ToString method itself, as a function of `unit -> string`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to the assembly in your C# project, not your F# project.  Of course, FSharp.Core is referenced by default in an F# project.  This page explains how: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

The other problem is that you forgot the parentheses in your `ToString` call. This line:

```
(T1 Best).ToString,T2 Best
```

should be this instead:

```
(T1 Best).ToString(),T2 Best
```

The code you wrote returns a tuple whose first element is not the result of calling ToString(); it is the ToString method itself, represented as an F# function of type `unit -> string`.